# Firebase Firestore Document Count returns into nil value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

Im devloping an iOS application using Firebase Firestore. However, I come across a problem, when I return the document count value, it's always nil. If I do the print method, it prints the items in the collection

```
    // Variable
    var itemsInttt: Int

    
    // Collectionsview
         func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                dataBase.collection("Channels").getDocuments { (document, error) in
                    self.itemsInttt = (document?.documents.count)!
// The print works
                    print((document?.documents.count)!)
                    self.itemsInttt = documentData!.count
                }
// This is where it crashes
                return itemsInttt
            }
```

Here is the full `viewcontroller.swift` file

https://github.com/Ashwin-Paudel/stackoverflowviewconttroller/blob/main/ViewController.swift

The code is a little bit messy

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong or even provide sample code

Thanks!

Comment: Firestore queries are asynchronous and always return immediately, before your callback is invoked.

Comment: Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

1. Don't input an asynchronous method into the collection view's delegate; give it an array count like `someArray.count`.
2. Fill that array before you reload the collection view using your `getDocuments` method. When Firestore returns and you've filled that array, then reload the collection view. The delegate method will use the size of that array to determine how many cells to render.
3. Always safely unwrap snapshots from Firestore, never force unwrap them, especially when you haven't even checked for errors.
4. Learn about asynchronous functions and how they work; things will make much more sense when you do. Remember, the `numberOfItemsInSection` delegate method is called right when the view controller is loaded, so putting an async method in there is useless because it takes time to call Firestore and get a response.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of code? Im trying all your tips but it ends up crashing

Comment: Post your view controller.

Comment: Here is  link to `viewcontroller.swift`  https://github.com/Ashwin-Paudel/stackoverflowviewconttroller/blob/main/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

[There is a blog post in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html) about this issue covering Swift Closures
similar to other programming promises/futures.

As indicated by @bsod. Basically, the approach is to work with callbacks instead of waiting for the result to be populated.